# Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1. error in gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

i'm trying to compile my project but i get this error, i tried to resolve my problem with other answers but nothing helped:

> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3.
>   Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.pom'.
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

**

my Gradle app looks like this:
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.0"
    // buildToolsVersion "29"
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.a1.makeitapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
//        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
//        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:fcm:1.18.5'
        // implementation 'com.android.support:design:REPLACE-WITH-APPCOMPAT-VERSION'

    }
}
```

my Gradle :

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

can someone help to solve the problem??
thanks!!

Comment: try removing "google()" from repositories in your Gradle

Comment: @Azhagthott - I tried this kind of things tons of times... didn't help

Comment: I had a similar issue and was because I was using maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } and google() =/